# Could this be classed as an attempt to answer the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37776414/2422013) as being NAA (Not An Answer) due to it being written like a comment:

[image]

I consequently flagged it and the flag was declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

To me the answer is not an answer as it reads like a comment. It's true that it could be edited to look like an answer (but so could most NAAs), but that would simply be polishing a turd™.

Even if it is an answer, it is incorrect (however I did not flag because it is incorrect). The question I was asking here was whether *this specific answer can be classed as an answer*, which the duplicate target does not cover. To quote the first line of the 'not what to flag' section:

> Any post that attempts to answer the question

This question aimed to establish whether this was an attempt to answer the question.

Is this an answer? 
If so, what makes it an answer?

Comment: It looks like a bad answer to me. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: It's not NAA. It's just a poor answer with no explanation, stated in an unconfident fashion.

Comment: I would be surprised if the answer was *correct*, and it may well have been added in a kneejerk reaction to deprecated API usage, but in principle there's no reason it *couldn't* be right. It's just wrong, not NAA.

Comment: The person who posted the answer is a new user with a rep of 1, you need a min. rep of 50 to post comment, perhaps that's why he posted that as an answer instead of comment. As someone who joined the site very recently, I can speak from personally experience how disencouraging and unwelcomed one feels when you get down voted for your first attempt at answering question (worse if no explanation is given), so instead of rushing to down vote, why not comment first, ask him to improve his answer, as his answer looks to be not directly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer *attempts* to answer the question. However, I'm not sure if it's correct or not. It suggests using `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect`.

This answer should be downvoted, while dropping a comment asking for clarification or further explanation on why this should solve the problem - but I don't think it should be flagged as NAA.